# Custom Nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, nameserver

Ok, I've searched for the past 6 hours and can't figure this out.

I have several domains, in shared hosing I set the nameserver as `ns1.my-hosting-company.com` & `ns2.my-hosting-company.com`

Now I want to setup a VPS so I created a domain `my-custom-name-server.com` and added glue record to a static IP so :-

`ns1.my-custom-name-server.com` == `1.2.3.4`

`ns2.my-custom-name-server.com` == `1.2.3.4`

Now I want to use this name server for all my domains

- example.com
- example.net
- example.tld

When I add the nameserver for example.com as `ns1.my-custom-name-server.com` it isn't working.

The reason for this setup is if I move to a different server I just need to update `ns1` & `ns2` of `my-custom-name-server.com`

**Update**

Finally !!! it worked.. oh the joy when it worked ;-)

This is what got me to the solution.

- INPUT Port 53 needs to open.
- I was using bind9 listen-on port 53 in named.conf should have been **any**

**Vanity Server**

For professionally managed this is solution I was looking for :-

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-vanity-or-branded-nameservers-with-digitalocean-cloud-servers

Comment: Why would you want to run your own name servers? Is there some specific reason you need to do this? IMHO it's better to use your domain registrar name servers, or a third party service like Route53 / CloudFlare. In that case you modify your A / CNAME records to use the new IP address.

Comment: Agreed. Don't run your own nameservers.

Comment: Define "move to a different server". Do you mean move your website?

Comment: Assuming I want to host 100's of domains and later I want to move to a different hosting would I need to update 100's of A records?

Comment: @joeqwerty move to a different hosting company.

Comment: Define "move to a different hosting company". What exactly would be moving and why would this require you to change your name servers? I'm trying to get an understanding of exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you're talking about moving services, applications, servers from one hosting company to another then that merely means making changes to the appropriate DNS resource records. You don't need to have your own name servers to do that. You can just as easily make those changes at the registrar, Route53, or whomever is hosting your DNS. In the long run it's better to let the people who manage DNS for a living do it for you then for you to do it yourself.

Comment: @joeqwerty Sure but if I move hundreds of site wouldn't I have to update hundreds of A records ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56336/discussion-between-samosa-and-joeqwerty).

Comment: `if I move hundreds of site wouldn't I have to update hundreds of A records ?` - Sure, but you have to do that regardless of where your DNS is hosted. Hosting your own name servers doesn't mean not having to change the A records when you move the websites to a new webhost.

Comment: Check out this project, written and open-sourced by the team that runs all of the stack exchange sites. Once in use, it makes it absolutely trivial to change DNS providers. https://github.com/StackExchange/dnscontrol

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, you may have abandoned this approach, but the reason for the error is probably that you have not defined `my-custom-name-server.com` on your nameserver or it doesn't have A/AAAA and NS records for `ns1` and `ns2`.